# Apache giraph compile using maven

Tags: hadoop, giraph

I want to modify some examples in Apache giraph.
And using maven command "mvn compile; mvn package", I compiled the code and that succeed.
But when I run that example by hadoop, that change doesn't appear.
Have I use command "mvn install"?

Comment: How do you run your code?

Answer (score 0):

For developing new giraph examples, you do not need to modify the giraph-example classes. Instead, make a new project and reference to giraph jar files, create a new class that extends AbstractComputation, and override compute function. Then, create a jar file from your project and pass it by -libjars in your command.